# Is "commerical" a valid and different word from "commercial"?

Tags: orthography, writing, is-it-a-word, typographical-errors

Googling, I see many places using the spelling [*commerical*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22commerical%22&oq=%22commerical%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j35i39j0l4.3519j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), but I don't see that spelling in any dictionaries at all. Is it a mistake for *commercial*, or are these two different words?

Comment: It's a chimera of commercial and comical.

Comment: so what does it mean then ?

Comment: @HotLicks A very creative guess (even if you were mostly joking)! Nevertheless, just in case, let me say that I see no evidence that anyone has ever used it that way. All I see is many, many examples where it is obviously a misspelling; see my answer, below, which also includes a speculation about what such a portmanteau could mean.

Comment: @tchrist But it's not obvious that it's a typo. For a little while I thought Hot Licks's comment could be onto something. It took some work to convince myself that it is almost certainly a typo in all cases.

Comment: @tchrist You may be right, of course. Note, however, that N-Grams prove little in cases like this. Run one for 'buffalo,beefalo' and you'll get similar ratios to what you got for 'commercial,commerical', even though *beefalo* is definitely a word, see [here](http://americanbeefaloassociation.com/). After all, some legitimate words are just far more infrequent than others.

Comment: @linguisticturn I feel this is obviously a typo because the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between *beefalo* and *buffalo* is much greater than the one between *commerical* and *commercial*. Beyond that, the QWERTY keyboard layout requires subtle agility and coördination within the left hand and deft balancing against the right hand to pull off: ≕ʟ3ꜜ, ≕ʀ4ꜛ, ≕ʀ3ꜜʀ3ꜜ, **≕ʟ3ꜛ, ≕ʟ2ꜛ, ≕ʟ3ꜜ, ≕ʀ3ꜛ**, ≕ʟ5, ≕ʟ4. Compare escalating error rates in books of 1800/1900/2000 to see the clear effect of the typowriter vs manuscript originals.

Comment: @tchrist Incidentally, according to [this Levenshtein distance calculator](https://planetcalc.com/1721/), 'buffalo,beefalo' and 'commercial,commerical' have the same Levenshtein distance, 2.

Comment: @tchrist On the other hand, they do differ in their [Damerau–Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance), which is still 2 for  'buffalo,beefalo'  but is 1 for 'commercial,commerical' because transposition of two adjacent characters counts as a single operation in that metric (see e.g. [this calculator](http://fuzzy-string.com/Compare/Transform.aspx?r=buffalo&q=beefalo)). Be all that as it may, thank you for suspending your disbelief regarding this question!

Answer (score 8):

In virtually all cases, *commer**ic**al* is simply a misspelling of *commer**ci**al*. (Your question is a rare—and perhaps only—example where it is not!).

Many of the hits that show up in the google search you linked to are **obviously** misspellings of *commercial*. Consider [this one](https://gelbvieh.org/genetic-technology/maternaledgeprofile), for example. The title says *Commer**ic**al DNA Testing*, but in the text it says *To order tests, download the AGA Commer**ci**al DNA Testing form and follow these instructions*. Similarly [here](https://bendgoods.com/pages/commerical-projects): *commer**ic**al* in the title, but *commer**ci**al* in the text.

Let's also look at the twitter hashtag #commer**ic**al. Again, most of the tweets there clearly meant *commer**ci**al* but misspelled it. This is particularly clear in cases where the word *commer**ci**al* appears in the body of the tweet, e.g. [here](https://twitter.com/Max_Opps/status/1085801466684731392). Some tweeter users have pointed out such mistakes, e.g. [this one](https://twitter.com/phantomphreak00/status/1085196716494643200). One tweeter user, 'Roto-Rooter Plumbing', frequently tweets both with #commer**ci**al and with #commer**ic**al (see [here](https://twitter.com/RotoSpringfield)), but I can't see any difference between the two sets of posts.

In short, while it's hard to prove a negative, what I've seen so far leads me to believe that *commer**ic**al* is in virtually all cases simply a misspelling of *commer**ci**al* (there is at least one exception: your question). So far I see no evidence that *commer**ic**al* is some sort of [neological](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/neological) [portmanteau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) of *commer**ci**al* and *comical*.

**What if *commer***ic**al were a real word (which it does not appear to be)**

Having said all that, Hot Licks's comment is correct (even if it was meant mostly as a joke) when it says that *commer**ic**al* **could** be such a portmanteau. In fact, there are arguably situations in which it can be quite tempting to think that *commer**ic**al* could be such a portmanteau, for example when considering odd, surprising, or funny facts having to do with commer**ci**al activity or with advertising. For example, [this page](https://whatever.scalzi.com/2012/01/27/todays-interesting-commerical-discovery/) is about an unexpected fact concerning retail, and it originally contained the typo *commer**ic**al*. In the comments, we find the following exchange:

A commenter:

> Commerical = Commercial + Comical
>   or just a typo?

The blogger:

> Typo. Will fix.

The commenter was confused because, in the particular context of that blog post, it was entirely believable that someone could invent and use such a portmanteau, and moreover it is more or less clear what it would mean if it were used.

(At this point one may do a google search for 'commerical AND comical' to see if anyone commented on such usage. There are only 162 hits as of the time of this writing, and so it is possible to scan them all. I've done this, and it seems that in all of them *comme**ri**cal* is a typo after all. This strengthens the case for claiming that *comme**ri**cal* is **always** a typo.)

So let me try to flesh out what the meaning of *commer**ic**al* might be if it were a real word. It would *probably* be an adjective, and it might denote several different things.

One possibility would be a humorous commer**ci**al (advertisement). Sample usage: *that new commer**ic**al Pepsi advertisement uses humor to good advantage*.

Another meaning could be some action that some business took that inadvertently turned out to be funny in an embarrassing way. Sample usage: *They tried to appear serious in their sales pitch, but their presentation ended up being a prime example of a commer**ic**al misstep.*

To repeat, I see no evidence that *commer**ic**al* actually **is** used by anyone in either of the ways presented above. And I don't think it will be, for the simple reason that *commer**ic**al* and *commer**ci**al* are simply too similar and so too easily confused when written (though, admittedly, not when they are spoken).

Comment: As policy is unclear, and perhaps merits, I’ve cancelled my close vote to let the community have their say about this. Happy Levenshteining and fingerpoking!

Answer (score 4):

"Commerical" is a typo for "commercial". [Link.](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&q=%22commercial%22&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi26rKbvvrfAhVSShUIHTdeAxkQBQgrKAA&biw=1292&bih=697)

From the [Cambridge dictionary:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/commercial)

> related to buying and selling things

Example uses:

> Unlike the other commercial states of the 7th and 6th centuries B.C.,
> e.g.
>
> Then I got smart and checked all non-commercial vehicles.
>
> In addition to the storage buildings, he owns an insurance agency, a bank
> and a bunch of commercial real estate.